# How to override a parent theme's add_image_size and $content_width in the child theme's functions.php

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am trying to override some functions in a parent theme, 
I want to override `add_image_size` from 590 to 800 and `$content-width` from 590 into 850.

Here is the functions.php of the parent theme.

---

```
class WPEX_Theme_Class {

    public function __construct() {     
        // Theme setup: Adds theme-support, image sizes, menus, etc.
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( &$this, 'setup' ), 10 );
    }       


    public function setup() {
        // Set content width variable
        global $content_width;
        if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
            $content_width = 590;
        }

        // Add theme support        
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        // Add image sizes
        add_image_size( 'wpex-entry', 590, 9999, false );
        add_image_size( 'wpex-post', 590, 9999, false );
    }

  $blogger_theme_setup = new WPEX_Theme_Class;
}
```

---

This is my try:

```
function __construct() 
{
     add_action('after_setup_theme', array($this, 'change_theme'));
}

function change_theme() 
{
    remove_action('add_image_size', 'setup');
    add_action('wpex-post', array($this, 'setup'));
}

function setup() {

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    // Add image sizes
    add_image_size( 'wpex-entry', 800, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'wpex-post', 800, 9999, false );

 }
```

It is not working, what do I need to change?

Comment: why have you italicized your entire question?  What are you trying to override?  What have you tried in your child theme functions.php?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to override add_image_size from 590 into 800 and I want to add another menu. I tried a lot of code and get this error . Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WPEX_Theme_Class' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-content\themes\bloger-child\functions.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-settings.php(508): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-config.php(90)

Comment: Edit your question question to include your objective and also include the code of at least one of your attempts.  Get rid of the italics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove image size & add image size in child theme funcions.php not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790407/remove-image-size-add-image-size-in-child-theme-funcions-php-not-working)

Comment: no i get this error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_image_size() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-includes\media.php:292) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-content\themes\bloger-child\functions.php on line 29

Comment: The error message says the problem is that you are redeclaring `add_image_size()` on line 29 of functions.php. So what is on line 29 of functions.php? Do you have your own function called `add_image_size` there?

Comment: I see the problem - the answer I linked to tells you what to do but it doesn't actually tell you what code you need to use. It does includes the code for the `add_image_size()` function to show you what it does, so my guess is that you copied the `add_image_size` function into your code. You can remove that function and any other code you had that you were using to try this. I've written the functions you need in my answer below. Don't forget to regenerate your images and clear your cache! Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following code to your child theme will redeclare the image sizes and content_width.

You don't need to remove the image sizes set by the parent theme - you can override them by calling your `add_image_size` function *after* the parent theme calls it.

We can do this by use a lower priority for `add_action`. The parent theme uses `10` so we can use `11`.

```
// use priority 11 to hook into after_setup_theme AFTER the parent theme
 add_action('after_setup_theme', 'reset_parent_setup', 11);

function reset_parent_setup() 
{
    // Override the image sizes
    add_image_size( 'wpex-entry', 800, 9999, false );
    add_image_size( 'wpex-post', 800, 9999, false );

    // Set content width variable
    global $content_width;
    $content_width = 850;
}
```

**Note:**

`add_image size` doesn't automatically create new versions of images that are already uploaded, so **don't forget to regenerate your images afterwards**! 
You might also need to clear any cache that could affect it.

---

**UPDATE: Check if the correct size has been registered**

The function below will print the size for your two image sizes, wpex-entry and wpex-post. Add this to your functions.php to check what they are (Note: the `die()` function will stop the rest of the page from being displayed to make it easier to see the values being displayed):

```
add_action('loop_start', 'debug_image_sizes');
function debug_image_sizes() {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['wpex-entry'] ) ){
        echo '<p>wpex-entry Image Size: </p><pre>';
        var_dump( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['wpex-entry'] );
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    else echo "<p>wpex-entry Image Size not found!!</p>";

    if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['wpex-post'] ) ){
        echo '<p>wpex-post Image Size: </p><pre>';
        var_dump( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['wpex-post'] );
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    else echo "<p>wpex-post Image Size not found!!</p>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I did cleared the cache but with no chance

Comment: @user3438908 When you say it "doesn't work", what is happening? e.g. Are you getting an error, are the images not being created? I've updated my answer with a function to check what the sizes are registered as - try it and let me know which size it shows.

Comment: array(3) {
  ["width"]=>
  int(590)
  ["height"]=>
  int(9999)
  ["crop"]=>
  bool(false)
}

Comment: Thank you,but if i got an error i would write i get an error not it doesn't work

Comment: Duh! I've just realised I copied your code into my answer but forgot to change the first function!! You don't need the `__construct` function, just the `add_action` call - see updated answer. Re. your comment - you would be surprised by how many people just say "it doesn't work" instead of giving us the error message, so I always check :)

Comment: Now I get this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-content\themes\bloger-child\functions.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-settings.php(508): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-config.php(90): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wasfaaty\index.php(17): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')

Comment: @user3438908 If you are not using a class for this then you don't need to use `$this`, it is just `add_action('after_setup_theme', 'reset_parent_setup', 11);`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer,but I have tried that before and didn't work by means it didn't give any error and the page loaded

Comment: Yes, but were you setting the *priority* in the `add_action` function to higher than ' 10'  then? You didn't show that in your question so I assumed you weren't as that was the only change you needed to make to what you had (unless something else is causing the problem). Try using the `debug_image_sizes` function now to see what it says - that way we can check whether the problem is with the sizes getting reset or not getting changed at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215849/discussion-between-user3438908-and-fluffykitten).